# How can something be perpendicular to a circular motion?

Tags: coriolis-effect, visualization

I recently forgot about the coriolis effect and revisited it. This resulted in a question, how can something be perpendicular to a circular motion? If the effect causes a force upon an object in the system, and the force goes perpendicular to the motion of the system, how is that possible? I need help on visualizing this, and if anyone could assist me in understanding this it would be great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tie a string to a weight and swing it around your head. Then have someone take a photo of it. What do you see? At the time the photo was taken, the weight was traveling in a certain direction, and the string was pulling it at right angles to that direction. If the motion of the weight is circular, that does not mean its direction is circular. It only means the direction changes from one instant to the next, but the string does too, so at any point in time it is perpendicular.

Comment: Of course, your body is also perpendicular to the motion...

Comment: @chrylis Your body would be perpendicular only if you spin following the motion.